# Early 80s sci-fi movie, cyborg(?), shooting .. had this stuck in my mind for about 30 years

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

This is an incredibly vague scene depiction, but I'm trying to recall a sci-fi movie I watched as a very young kid. It would have been out perhaps early 80s.

I don't recall any of the story but the image has stuck in my head and for years I always wanted to know what the movie was about. I recall a man (possibly a cyborg) who carried a shield, and for the scene I recalled drove/hovered around on something that resembled a segway or a one person standing hover craft. There was a lot of shooting going on. He may (may!) have had red infared vision like terminator (although I may just be getting that part mixed up with terminator :) I know if I saw the scene again, I'd sure to recognize it.

Anyway if anyone has the slightest inclination to what film this may be, I'd love to hear. Sorry there isn't much more I recall, I guess this is the last chance for me to put this to bed :)

Comment: Space Mutiny?  That had shooting, at least.

Comment: Hmm 1988, it would have been sooner than that. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be thinking of [The Eliminators](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091003/). The timing fits, and the trailer has most everything you're describing: a guy with a shield, a cyborg on a one-person vehicle (though it's tank treads, not a hovercraft), and shooting.

Comment: Haha, that is totally it! Completely different from how I recall it, I just remember the cyborg guy. Don't remember a ninja, and the action guy (although I vaguely recall the woman). Anyway looks terrible, can't wait to watch it :) I see the full length movie is on YouTube too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's cool moments like this that make me like this site. Happy to see that the mystery was solved after all these years :D

Comment: Wow - the movie features both Tasha Yar AND a Borg drone a year before TNG aired. I call time-travel hijinks.

Comment: @Omegacron It's Tasha's home planet, before she joined Starfleet.

Comment: ELIMINATORS: (Fox, 1986) D: Peter Manoogian S: Paul De Meo, Danny Bilson P: Charles Band. A vengeful "mandroid" is played by R.J. Reynolds tobacco heir Patrick Reynolds. This PG movie throws in everything: a lesbian river queen, a flying robot, a prehistoric tribe, kung fu. Andrew Prince as a riverboat pilot costars with Denise Crosby as a scientist and Conan Lee as Ninja. It was shot in Spain but is set in South America. ("Psychotronic Video Guide" by Michael Weldon. p. 182)