# 80s or 90s movie - Asian man jumps through large spinning fan

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't have much to go by here... but I'll give it a shot. I would have to say this movie was set in the late 80's early 90's. (May possibly be an episode of a TV show)

I remember one of the characters was an Asian guy who at one point jumps through a spinning fan/vent. The jump is in slow motion, and he lands on the other side of the spinning fan blades and kicks the fan from the other side to stop the blades from spinning, allowing the other people with him to get through.

I wanna say that the main character/hero is sort of a Robocop-type character. I even thought at one point that it WAS Robocop.. but I skimmed through the Robocop movies and couldn't find any familiar scenes. I remember that the three heroes of the movie were this potential "Robocop-like dude", the Asian dude, and a kid. There may have been a forth but I can't remember. At the very end of the movie, the "bad guy" was in some sort of air craft or space ship or laboratory or something, and he laughs just before the whole place explodes. I'm pretty sure the bad guy had a beard and mustache.

Answer (score 11):

This is "[Eliminators](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091003/)" (1986). He's a cyborg, she's a hottie, there's an asian dude as well.

> *As part of their experiments in time travel, Drs. Reeves and Takada
>   construct a cyborg "Mandroid" with the body of a downed pilot. After
>   the success of the initial experiments, Reeves decides to have the
>   Mandroid scrapped. Not wishing to be taken apart, Mandroid flees with
>   the help of Dr. Takeda, who is killed for his disobedience. Distraught
>   by the death of his one friend, the Mandroid goes north to America in
>   search of someone who can help him in getting revenge and stopping Dr.
>   Reeves in whatever evil plan he intends to use his time machine for.*

You can see the 'fan scene' at 1:21.00

Comment: For the record, this film is awful. I mean "Time Chasers" awful. Instead of watching this, why not spend that hour clearing your attic, having a long bath or learning to make the perfect pancake?

Comment: Holy crap! This is it! Thank you so much! It has been driving me crazy for years trying to find this movie. That scene is exactly how I remember it! I may be forced to try and watch it and suffer the "I lost two hours of my life feeling" just to rekindle my youth. Thanks again!!!

Comment: The Eliminators is popular lately: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74121/early-80s-sci-fi-movie-cyborg-shooting-had-this-stuck-in-my-mind-for-abo/74208#74208