# Cyborg movie from the 80s where the protagonist dies in a plane crash and is made into a cyborg

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for an older cyborg movie. In the beginning the protagonist dies in a plane crash, and later is made into a cyborg. Can't remember most of the movie, but at the end his maker turns himself into a red cyborg and fights him. They each have a half head still human and the other half has a red eye.

Answer (score 1):

Quite probably *[Eliminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliminators_(1986_film))*

[image: The Eliminators - Move Poster]

> Eliminators is a 1986 science fiction action film directed by directed by Peter Manoogian, starring Andrew Prine, Denise Crosby and Patrick Reynolds. The plot centers around a "Mandroid" constructed by an evil scientist from the body of a downed pilot, who teams up with the scientist responsible for android technology, her pet robot Spot, a riverboat guide, and a martial arts warrior.

....

> Arriving in South America, Hunter hires the best river boat captain she can find in a seedy bar, one Harry Fontana, and they head down a river. After running afoul of rival riverboat captains and Reeves' men, they end up finding the Mandroid's crashed plane after an encounter with a tribe of cavemen brought to this time by Reeves' time travel experiments. They also meet Kuji, the ninja son of Doctor Takada, who has come to find his father. The Mandroid informs him that his father is dead, killed by Reeves. He joins the group, which then storms Reeves' headquarters, only to be captured by Reeves, now a cyborg himself, more advanced than the Mandroid, whose body is designed to look like Roman armor. Reeves plans to travel back to ancient Rome and become the new Caesar.

[image: Mandroid outside of his tank] [image: Reeves as a cyborg]

Comment: This one comes up fairly often on the site. If it is the correct one, please click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75826/80s-or-90s-movie-asian-man-jumps-through-large-spinning-fan/75846#75846 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/74121/23243